# Regex mach two tags from html sample text at the same time

Tags: javascript, regex

I have problem with regexp.

This is a sample text:
`<h4>HEADER</h4><p>Test document: <a id="1" linktype="document">TEST DOKUMENT TXT</a>. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#x27;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p><embed alt="grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" embedtype="image" format="left" id="7"/>`

From this sample I need to extract `<a id="1" linktype="document">TEST DOKUMENT TXT</a>` and `<embed alt="grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" embedtype="image" format="left" id="7"/>` tags at the same time. I cannot do this separately.

So far, I have regex `(\<a|<embed .*?\/>)/g` but it doesn't work for whole `<a>` tag.

Here is a live demo https://regexr.com/4qnhj

Could someone help me?

https://regexr.com/4qnhj

Comment: Why can't you do it separately and why not use DOM Parsing?

Comment: Why not `$(SomeContent).find('a,embed')`?

**FYI** Don't use regex for HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: @Justinas Im getting this text as a string, it just looks like HTML

Comment: @Ewelina If it's valid HTML, then you can parse in via jQuery (or vanilla JS in hard way) and act with it as normal DOM

Comment: @Justinas What hard way. See my answer. Not hard at all

Comment: Does it matter what attributes are in either the `a` or `embed` tags ? Or, whether they are open or standalone ? Also,  if it is matched globally there will probably be a large amount matched on a big page.

Comment: https://regexr.com/4qo45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex to extract html

```js
const str = `<h4>HEADER</h4><p>Test document: <a id="1" linktype="document">TEST DOKUMENT TXT</a>. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#x27;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p><embed alt="grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" embedtype="image" format="left" id="7"/>`
let domSnippet = document.createElement("div");
domSnippet.innerHTML=str;
console.log(domSnippet.querySelectorAll("a, embed"))
```

jQuery

```js
const str = `<h4>HEADER</h4><p>Test document: <a id="1" linktype="document">TEST DOKUMENT TXT</a>. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#x27;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p><embed alt="grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" embedtype="image" format="left" id="7"/>`
let $domSnippet = $("<div/>").html(str);
console.log($domSnippet.find("a, embed"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```